# IllegalArgumentException when update firebase library

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, illegalargumentexception

My Android app work fine before I update firebase libs. After updating to the newest firebase lib I got following Exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-4
    Process: com.sound.booster.extra.volume, PID: 24298
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Please set your project ID. A valid Firebase project ID is required to communicate with Firebase server APIs: It identifies your project with Google.
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkNotEmpty(Unknown Source:8)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.1.7:52)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.1.7:2)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.1.7:1)
```

Src before update libs:

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:19.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
```

Src after update libs:

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:19.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.1'
```

Could anyone explain why and how to fix this issue?

Comment: it says your firebase id is gone or changed!

Comment: tks u! I missed setProjectId method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Newer versions of the Firebase SDKs depends on a service called Firebase Installations Service, which adds some extra requirements on the configuration data about the Firebase project that you include in your application. In your case it seems that you're missing a project ID in this configuration.

If you configure the Firebase project for your app by including a `google-services.json` in your app, the solution is typically to get the latest version of that file from the Firebase console and update in your app.

If you configure the Firebase project for your app explicitly in code, you will need to make sure that you call the [`setProjectId` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseOptions.Builder#setProjectId(java.lang.String)) in there.

Also see:

- [FirebaseInstallationsException on latest version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61513995/firebaseinstallationsexception-on-latest-version/61515375#61515375)
- [Firebase cannot communicate with Firebase Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61516255/firebase-cannot-communicate-with-firebase-server/61553958#61553958)
- the [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#2020-02-27) of the SDK version where this new dependency was introduced

Comment: Tks u!! setProjectId method is exactly thing that I missed.. So ashamed!