# Firebase token not produce when implement FirebaseMessagingService

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

When I try to get Firebase Token it give me error. :
Please set your project ID. A valid Firebase project ID is required to communicate with Firebase server APIs: It identifies your project with Google.

Anyone can give suggestion how to solve this.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61892913/7746134

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the firebase **project_id[image]** to the res/values/strings.xml

```
  <string name="project_id" translatable="false">XXXXXXX</string>
```